# Python : Accessing dictionary; polyline segments

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with street names as keys and co-ordinates as values as below.

{'"a street"': '(2,2) (3,1) (4,-1)', 
'"b street"': '(1,1) (5,1)', 
'"c street"': '(5,1) (6,6)'}

I want to check if there is intersection between each street with all the other streets using the street co-ordinates. Is there any simple way to go for it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do 3 coordinates represent? You can get line intersections with a dot product.

Comment: 3 co-ordinates are the co-ordinates of street a. It is basically represented by poly-line segments. Each co-ordinate is connected to the successive co-ordinate to form the street.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode that might spark some ideas as to how to implement the multi-line interesection problem, consider trying to implement these functions:

```
def coords_string_to_list_of_tuples(str):
    ...

def line_from_two_tuples(tuple1,tuple2):
    ...

def line_intersects_line():
    ...

def check_intersection(line1, line2):
    ...

def print_intersections():
    for each street s:
        coord_tuple_list = coords_string_to_list_of_tuples(list[s])
        for each street s2:
            if s1 ≠ s2:
                print check_intersection(list[s], list[s2])
```

I hope these ideas provide guidance.

Comment: Thanks Felipe. I will try this!

Comment: I'm happy to help, I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Yeah it did solve my problem. Thanks again for your guidance :) One issue that I face now is, check is being done for same street co-ordinates twice.. Once in outer loop and once in inner loop. But intersection check still works fine. So the desired result is obtained without any problem but I m working on avoiding duplication in check.

Comment: set(list(1,1,1,2)) == set(1,2)